Laravel Sail MySQL Connection Refused - Docker Setup Issue
Description:
I am currently setting up a Laravel project using Docker and Laravel Sail. I am facing issues connecting to the MySQL service from the Laravel application. The error message indicates that the connection is being refused.
Environment:

Laravel version: 10.10
Docker version: v27.0.3
MySQL version: 8.0.32
Operating System: Windows 11 WSL version: 2.2.4.0 (Windows Subsystem for Linux 2)

Problem:
When I attempt to run the Laravel migrations or connect to the MySQL service from the Laravel container, I receive a "Connection refused" error.
Error Logs:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'laravel' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

Steps to Reproduce:

Set up Laravel Sail with the following docker-compose.yml:

version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local


Environment configuration in .env and .env.testing files:

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=newpassword


Start the services:

./vendor/bin/sail up -d


Attempt to run the migrations:

./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate --env=testing

Expected Behavior:
Laravel should connect to the MySQL database and run the migrations successfully.
Actual Behavior:
The connection is refused, and the following error is returned:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified that MySQL is running:

./vendor/bin/sail exec mysql mysqladmin -u root -p status

Output indicates MySQL is running:
Uptime: 804  Threads: 2  Questions: 59  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 120  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 39  Queries per second avg: 0.073


Checked MySQL logs:

./vendor/bin/sail logs mysql

Output:
mysql-1  | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.32-1.2.11-server
mysql-1  | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.32-1.2.11-server
mysql-1  | 2024-07-25T20:31:03.744066Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
mysql-1  | 2024-07-25T20:31:03.744807Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 1
mysql-1  | 2024-07-25T20:31:03.750686Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql-1  | 2024-07-25T20:31:03.849883Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql-1  | 2024-07-25T20:31:03.967731Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql-1  | 2024-07-25T20:31:03.967761Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql-1  | 2024-07-25T20:31:03.981964Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql-1  | 2024-07-25T20:31:03.982031Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.32'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.


Verified MySQL is listening on port 3306:

./vendor/bin/sail exec mysql ss -tuln | grep 3306

Output confirms MySQL is listening on port 3306.

Ensured correct MySQL user privileges:

./vendor/bin/sail exec mysql mysql -u root -p
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sail'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;


Tried connecting to MySQL from the Laravel container:

./vendor/bin/sail exec laravel.test mysql -u sail -p -h mysql

Successful connection from the container.

Verified Docker network configuration:

docker network inspect web2_sail

Output indicates the network is properly configured:
[
    {
        "Name": "web2_sail",
        "Id": "d4b00fbf3c2778f704a2c3025e6f3db476acf6c4afe6b967a246bf4bbcccb91d",
        "Created": "2024-07-25T20:31:03.142662932Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0ed0e32a6b8c725be03d78959399043140cf97fc995ca0e0d38e2acd2aa7fd8f": {
                "Name": "web2-mysql-1",
                "EndpointID": "d2b25fb88d43d80468d6830b4b4839f80c2475d6eefa683798bd4fb086313bf8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "6541b649afb1482c08888c3b5590c04142979e1bf719598b8c52298a908bb04b": {
                "Name": "web2-laravel.test-1",
               

 "EndpointID": "0f655029a4258ab7fb7cfbee2d22535c25a844af30ba70045be234e92a85f669",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "sail",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "web2",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.28.1"
        }
    }
]


Tested connectivity from Laravel container:

./vendor/bin/sail exec laravel.test telnet mysql 3306

Output:
Trying 172.18.0.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

./vendor/bin/sail exec laravel.test nc -zv mysql 3306

Output:
nc: connect to mysql (172.18.0.2) port 3306 (tcp) failed: Connection refused


Verified MySQL configuration files:

./vendor/bin/sail exec mysql grep -r "bind-address" /etc/mysql

Output:
grep: /etc/mysql: No such file or directory


Created the testing database manually:

./vendor/bin/sail exec mysql mysql -u sail -p
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testing;

Request:
I need assistance identifying why the Laravel application cannot connect to the MySQL service within the Docker setup. Any insights or recommendations to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Revert DB_PASSWORD to its original value. DB_PASSWORD=password

Did you run sail then change password? Or run sail, change password, delete volume, then run docker-compose up?

@Mr.Kenneth I did both. I ran sail, changed password which didn't work. I also completely removed all docker containers & volumes and did a sail artisan build --no-cache and tried with the default settings again. No results so far, and I don't think it has to do with the password being incorrect.

It's a good issue. Stick to the defaults until everything works. You're stuck with this: MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'. See if you can connect with root user and password. See if you can add mysql to your hosts file

Sorry. I cannot leave comments. I installed Windows and tried to set up Laravel with your parameters. It worked when I changed DB_CONNECTION to localhost and IP address...
